# AMP-list for email fail to load sample json

Tags: json, amp-email, amp-list

I'm new to AMP and I'm a creative designer so my knowledge of front-end backend is limited. I trying to do an AMP email which load info from json and display it in the email.

I'm using sample AMP-list component script from https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list/?format=email, everything work fine but when I replace the json link with my sample file it didn't work https://wegoexperience.com/dest.json

Anyone can advice why? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the AMP HTML markup you used that didn't work? Folks here can't really advice without that piece of information. From a quick glance, your JSON items contain properties like `img` and `dest`, which don't match any of the JSON provided in the amp.dev documentation (e.g, `title`, `item`, `price`). That means your JSON won't work as a drop-in replacement for the sample AMP HTML provided by that page and you will most likely need to adjust the Mustache template to account for your own JSON properties.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: it's all about CORS, read here: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/cors-in-email/

In the sandbox on https://amp.dev/ you won't be able to check your own JSON.

If you have an Apache server, then create(in the folder where the JSON file is located) **.htaccess** file and write the following code there:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: "youaddress@youdomain.com"
Header add Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"
```

After that, AMP-list should work if you test locally or on your server.